# How to show icons only in Visual Studio windows

Tags: visual-studio

How can I show only the icons in visual studio windows? For example, the properties bar tab shows the icon and the text "Properties". Also the toolbox tab shows the icon the text "Toolbox". I would like to see only icons on tabs.

Do you know where this setting is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In VS2008 you can right click the toolbox and deselect "list view". This will change the view to icon, but only for the current tab.